# Poincare-like inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I would like to prove that there exists $C>0$ such that

$$\| u \|^2_{L^2(B(0,1))} \leq C \left ( \| \nabla u \|^2_{L^2(B(0,1))} + \| u \|^2_{L^2(\partial B(0,1))} \right )$$

for every $u \in C^\infty(\overline{B(0,1)})$, where $B(0,1)$ is the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

To me this looks similar to a Poincare inequality except that it compensates for the fact that $u$ may not be zero on the boundary. With this in mind, I tried manipulating the version of the Poincare inequality where we subtract off the average so that it would look like this situation. With that I get a $C>0$ such that

$$\| u \|^2_{L^2(B(0,1))} \leq C \left ( \overline{u}^2 + \| \nabla u \|^2_{L^2(B(0,1))} \right )$$

where $\overline{u}$ is the average of $u$ over $B(0,1)$. Now I get stuck trying to relate $\overline{u}$ to $u$ on the boundary. From here I *would* want to show that $\overline{u}^2 \leq C \| u \|^2_{L^2(\partial B(0,1))}$. But that can't work, because we could have a nonzero function which is zero on the boundary yet strictly positive on the interior. Of course, in this case the result follows from the Poincare inequality for $H^1_0$. So this result seems to be somewhat like an interpolation between the Poincare inequality for $H^1_0$ and the Poincare inequality for $H^1$ functions with mean zero.

Any suggestions?

Comment: By $\lVert \nabla u \rVert^2_{L^2(B(0,1))}$ do you mean that the squared $L^2$ norm of the function $p \mapsto |\nabla u(p)|$?  Or do you have some other norm in mind?

Comment: @StevenGubkin That's correct.

Comment: One approach is by contradiction and using the Rellich compactness theorem.

Comment: @Jose27 So you're suggesting I essentially repeat the "standard" (i.e. "used in Evans") proof of the Poincare inequality for mean zero functions, *mutatis mutandis*?

Comment: @Jose27 That actually worked out very nicely. If you would like to make a very slightly more detailed answer I will accept it. (It does not really need full details, because I have a proof written out now.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Argue by contradiction: For every $k$ there exists $u_k$ with $\| u_k\|_{L^2(B)}=1$ and 
$$
\| \nabla u_k \|_{L^2(B)} + \| u_k\|_{L^2(\partial B)} \leq 1/k.
$$
Then $u_k\to 0$ weakly in $H^1$, this contradicts the fact that the $u_k$ have unit $L^2$ norm by Rellich's compactness theorem.

Comment: This is an old question, but maybe you can help me: Why does $u_k $ weakly converge in $H^1$? Also, where do you use Rellich's compactness theorem? Thanks for your help.